# delay between close(fd) and releasing of flock

Tags: c++, linux

I have a c++ class which basically opens a file in constructor, flock the fd in ReadAcquire() or WriteAcquire() member function like this: flock(fd, (IsReaderLock? LOCK_SH : LOCK_EX) | LOCK_NB), and closes the fd in Release() member function. Then I ran this test code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    FileLock lock1("/tmp/Test");
    VERIFY_IS_TRUE(lock1.WriteAcquire().IsSuccess());
    lock1.Release();
    FileLock lock2("/tmp/Test");
    VERIFY_IS_TRUE(lock2.ReadAcquire().IsSuccess());
    lock2.Release();
}
```

It works fine in a simple test program. but in a complex program (multi-threads running, lots of timers based on realtime signals, etc.), it often happens that the flock() call in ReadAcquire() or WriteAcquire() will fail with error code 11, i.e. EWOULDBLOCK, I never got a EINTR though. With retry, it usually recovers within max 5 retries of interval 1ms. Is there any explanation for this behavior? I assume close(fd) should immediately release the flock. thanks.

Comment: If you are multi-threading there could perhaps be some other thread being lucky and get a lock immediately after the `Release()`.

Comment: I don't know c that well, but it sounds like in your `complex program with multiple threads running, lots of timers` it might be that there is another thread locking that file just for a few milliseconds while another thread is waiting on that lock. This sounds like it would cause the 5ms of blocking time that you are getting, as `lock` and `close` isn't instantaneous.

Comment: In a "complex multithreaded program", I wouldn't rely on the (relatively) slow locking service of the OS (think about networked file systems...) - why don't you use classic MT mechanisms like mutexes to acquire exclusive access to the file? If you need to lock against *external* processes, you can still use `flock`once you made sure your thread is the only one in your process that can get to the file.

Comment: > will fail with error code 11, i.e. EWOULDBLOCK < which means that some thread is still holding the lock and since you're calling `flock` with `LOCK_NB` it immediately fails. How can you be sure that you are really released that lock?

Comment: Also note the manual page explicitly states that *converting a lock from shared to exclusive, or vice versa, is not atomic*

Comment: sorry I didn't clarify this: this piece of code runs in one thread, and /tmp/Test file is not used by other threads. so there should be no contention between threads wrt to this file lock. yes, we use file lock for inter-process locking, as well as inter-thread.. the release of flock is simply by close(fd), and I am sure it is there.I am not converting the lock from shared to exclusive: the code is simply creating a variable to do write-lock and release, then create another variable to do read-lock and release.

Comment: The file could also be locked by another process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  More urgently, though, you should read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've outlined some code, but it really isn't clear what's going on and the problem is as likely to be in some of the other code as in what you show (at least, as far as we can tell).  Producing an MCVE that reproduces the problem may be hard, but if it is hard for you to reduce your code, it is that much harder for us who don't even have your code to work with.  But 'minimal' is important; your code should be as small as possible.